# How to avoid the automatic exceed table size?

Tags: html

eg: my table height and width is 10:10. When i entered some paragraph inside table, unexpectedly the width(50) is increasing. Please give me solution for avoid that things.

Comment: please include html/css in your question

Comment: You can please put additional info as a comment to my answer, if you which to make it more complete and able to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if i'm aware of how text inside a  in a table are rendered, i put them inside a . You got, together with CSS, complete control of the text.

```
<table style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width:20px;height:20px;">'randomtext</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above snippet gives you a static box whatever you put into the div-tag. If you intend to hide  the characters that not fit in the size, just add `overflow:hidden`.

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;">'randomtext</div>
```

You may also use the `table-layout:fixed;` CSS attribute to the `<table style=''>` tag to achieve same effect. `overflow:hidden` give you same effect with table-layt, as in a DIV. I will point out avoiding the use of tables in design purposes (DIV's are the element for this). However I also will beg-pardon if I don't understand the question correctly. Your question could, at this time, be much more clear.

**A side note,**
If we say the example with a square height of 10 x 10 pixels. When you type in a `'` or something, the table are grow. Probably in height but maybe also in width depend on font-style. The `<div>` can override this. Even if the character are visibly smaller, like as a quote mark, there are space reserved for a box around a full size of that chosen size, font-face and encoding.